# Error: (jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. Error code from jupyter: 1)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

jupyter error: Has anyone experienced this and resolved it in VSCode? I have researched online with no luck. 
I started getting this error after i have upgraded my python from 3.7 to 3.8.1

Everything seems to have been installed correctly

T:>jupyter --version

jupyter core     : 4.6.1

jupyter-notebook : 6.0.2

qtconsole        : 4.6.0

ipython          : 7.11.0

ipykernel        : 5.1.3

jupyter client   : 5.3.4

jupyter lab      : 1.2.4

nbconvert        : 5.6.1

ipywidgets       : 7.5.1

nbformat         : 4.4.0

traitlets        : 4.3.3

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I actually had to install the 3.7 python version. There is an issue when using the last 3.8.1 and 3.8.2 versions, the ipkernel is not recognized in these last versions. 
Hope this helps those who are using Jupyter notebook in VS. Code.

Cheers.